# Show that $F(x,y) \le F_X(x)F_Y(y)$ for concave shaped PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $f$ and $F$ be the PDF and DF of a joint random variable $(X,Y)$ such that the determinant
$\begin{vmatrix}f(a_1, b_1) & f(a_1, b_2) \\ f(a_2, b_1) & f(a_2, b_2)\end{vmatrix} \le 0$ for $a_1 \le x \le a_2$ and $b_1 \le y \le b_2$

Then show that $F(x, y) \le F_X(x)F_Y(y)$

(I understand that the slope of the 2D surface is convex from the point $(a_1, b_1)$ to $(a_2, b_2)$. But I'm not able to figure out how to approach this problem.)

Please note that there is no assumption on the independence of the random variables.